# what can i do to bring back to life mi samsung galaxy a 51?

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, boot-loop, odin, hard-reset

Days ago my phone restarted and stopped on the android/samsung logo.

i tried to do a hard reset on the recovery menu, but when the process finished the phone stopped on the android logo again. i did this process many times but it happened again.

after that i tried using Odin3 to install an official firmware, the process finished successfully, but when it restarted again stopped on the logo. i turned off the phone with the power off and volume down buttons, then i used the recovery mode (i tried to much to access to it, i was thinking that i cannot access to) combination keys, i did the hard reset again, and it showed the charging icon (seems to be frozen with no animation, some times happens). i cant turn it on disconnected to the pc or charger.

Comment: how old is that device?

Comment: 6 months at least

Comment: Please claim it to seller under warranty we can't help you